# How should I handle asking for further information on a question?

Tags: discussion

A few days ago, I asked [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/81196/what-would-happen-if-i-removed-darkvision/82268?noredirect=1#comment184974_82268) question about removing darkvision. After talking to various people, including my players, reading answers and looking around on forums, I have come up with various things I could replace darkvision with.

I would like to ask a question about some of these replacements. The question would essentially be asking: "I have done some research on the number of racial traits each race gets. It seems to be about 4. How powerful are these substitute racial traits in comparison to darkvision?"

Should I edit that into the existing question, ask a new question, or do something else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a completely different question. So, ask it in a new question.

Questions should be asked together when they're intimately related and don't make much sense being asked separately.

The impacts of removing dark vision, and the power levels of various racial traits compared to dark vision, don't fit that criteria. They're separate issues that can quite easily be asked separately, and should.

Comment: But, if the original question provides a significant amount of context for the new question, it's ok to put a link to the former in the latter.